# How to update the local github checkout?

Tags: git, github

I have cloned a git repository from guthub a while ago. Changes have been made in the github repository.

Now I want to have locally what there is on github. I have tried the following commands:

```
>git pull
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> alex
```

and

```
>git pull master
fatal: 'master' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I do not care about any local changes. I just want a copy of what is in the github repo locally. Is there a `git` way to do that, or is it best to remove the local checkout completly and do a `git clone` again to start fresh?

Comment: have you tried "git pull origin master" ?

Comment: @Oswald: At first, it opened a text editor and wanted me to comment on a merge. I used the command a second time - and then it seemed to work. However, quite strange...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you're looking for is

```
git pull origin master
```

As it is in the documentation `git pull <remote> <branch>`. The word `origin` is the remote repository, `master` is the branch you are going to pull.